# Add credentials & set a specific role for a database

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can we add login credentials & roles for a particular database?

There is ServerObject,replication & management folders in MS SQLmanagement studio. What's the significance of these folders?

How can we add roles in MS SQLmanagement studio not for a particular database?

What are the main things that we should give more care when creating a database?

Comment: Too many questions inside. You should split this in many pieces.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Database Security Tutorial](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10432.database-security-tutorial.aspx) on ToadWorld (originally SQLServerPedia)